# Sorting by multiple columns not working - R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe as shown below:

```
    structure(list(DAILY_INJ_DATE = c("2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", 
"2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", 
"2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", 
"2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", 
"2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", 
"2020-04", "2020-05", "2020-06", "2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", 
"2020-10", "2020-11", "2020-12", "2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", 
"2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", 
"2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-06", 
"2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", 
"2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05", "2020-06", 
"2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", "2020-10", "2020-11", "2020-12"
), PID = c("42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", "42135311180000", 
"42135311180000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", "42135335900000", 
"42135335900000", "42135335900000"), InjIndex = c(3.1488349310755e-05, 
7.16470821042452e-05, 3.08198068625437e-05, 0.00365977544989287, 
0.000102146739534363, 6.97288098968181e-05, 6.67030385322113e-05, 
0.000101198808641258, 6.96471158898905e-05, 0.000100457907956119, 
0.002770103468248, 0.000141272149337637, 3.71747211895911e-05, 
0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0.00261196063305948, 0.0020329847793613, 0.0268256888287629, 
0.0190615086256689, 0.00165037617202441, 0.00823890291192408, 
0.0149562009694358, 3.82198063529811e-05, 0.00703837718531629, 
0.0460765131610604, 0.0571638755572333, 0.0600559821857274, 0.0636357826177028, 
0.0643659884529977, 0.0577969845601966, 0.0588167585535698, 0.0593479205060031, 
0.0478238114640216, 0.0579565073781893, 0.0439869629670818, 0.056714771440236, 
0.122274207049878, 0.136105301010138, 0.133225772135695, 0.126920643583703, 
0.128496063591315, 0.14043302451169, 0.113191351198699, 0.125443452699286, 
0.146339474772728, 0.0191599802822513, NA, 0.133221262910392, 
0.216814720357711, 0.606926958546271, NA, NA, 0.131402308568841, 
NA, 0.355567523506574, NA, 0.0234750006884004, 0.0416741137140514, 
NA, NA, 0.0585083175072382, NA, 0.0852075310970539, 0.0691143041976479, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 69L), class = "data.frame")
```

I intend to sort this table based first on  **increasing** '`PID`' column and then **descending** order of '`Daily_Inj_Date`' column.

I used the below syntax as:

```
df1 <- df[order(df$PID, -as.numeric(df$DAILY_INJ_DATE)),]
```

but the result I get is incorrect.
For ex., the last date for the **PID ='42135311180000'**  , is '**2020-12**'  but after performing the ordering,the resultant data frame shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is not a `Date` class and it can be converted to `Date` by `paste`ing the day as well, then convert to `Date` with `as.Date`, coerce to `numeric` and then do the `order`

```
df1 <-  df[order(df$PID, -as.numeric(as.Date(paste0(df$DAILY_INJ_DATE, "-01")))),]
```

-checking the output

```
subset(df1, substr(DAILY_INJ_DATE, 1, 4) == '2018')
#   DAILY_INJ_DATE            PID     InjIndex
#12        2018-12 42135311180000 1.412721e-04
#11        2018-11 42135311180000 2.770103e-03
#10        2018-10 42135311180000 1.004579e-04
#9         2018-09 42135311180000 6.964712e-05
#8         2018-08 42135311180000 1.011988e-04
#7         2018-07 42135311180000 6.670304e-05
#6         2018-06 42135311180000 6.972881e-05
#5         2018-05 42135311180000 1.021467e-04
#4         2018-04 42135311180000 3.659775e-03
#3         2018-03 42135311180000 3.081981e-05
#2         2018-02 42135311180000 7.164708e-05
#1         2018-01 42135311180000 3.148835e-05
#48        2018-12 42135335900000 1.463395e-01
#47        2018-11 42135335900000 1.254435e-01
#46        2018-10 42135335900000 1.131914e-01
#45        2018-09 42135335900000 1.404330e-01
#44        2018-08 42135335900000 1.284961e-01
#43        2018-07 42135335900000 1.269206e-01
#42        2018-06 42135335900000 1.332258e-01
#41        2018-05 42135335900000 1.361053e-01
#40        2018-04 42135335900000 1.222742e-01
#39        2018-03 42135335900000 5.671477e-02
#38        2018-02 42135335900000 4.398696e-02
#37        2018-01 42135335900000 5.795651e-02
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we can do this directly on the `Date` class converted column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df %>% 
    arrange(PID, desc(ymd(DAILY_INJ_DATE, truncated = 2)))
```

Comment: Thnks. I should have checked the type of the column 'date'. Silly mistake but a costly one.

Comment: @CodeMaster `Date` class is internally numeric.  So, coercing to numeric works on that, while on `character`, it returns NA with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be helpful for you if you separate the date and month column so that you can use `arrange`/`order` easily.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
 separate(DAILY_INJ_DATE, c('Year', 'Month'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE) %>%
 arrange(PID, desc(Year), desc(Month))

#   Year Month            PID   InjIndex
#1  2020    12 42135311180000 4.7824e-02
#2  2020    11 42135311180000 5.9348e-02
#3  2020    10 42135311180000 5.8817e-02
#4  2020     9 42135311180000 5.7797e-02
#5  2020     8 42135311180000 6.4366e-02
#6  2020     7 42135311180000 6.3636e-02
#7  2020     6 42135311180000 6.0056e-02
#8  2020     5 42135311180000 5.7164e-02
#9  2020     4 42135311180000 4.6077e-02
#...
```

If you want to combine the columns again you can add `unite` to above :

```
 %>% unite(DAILY_INJ_DATE, Year, Month, sep = '-')
```

Comment: Thnks! But it does require two steps to achieve the result. I do like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a string (`DAILY_INJ_DATE`) to a numeric:

```r
as.numeric(df$DAILY_INJ_DATE)

#  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [28] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [55] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

But this date string will sort well as a character without converting to a numeric or date.

```r
df[order(df$PID, df$DAILY_INJ_DATE, decreasing = c(FALSE, TRUE), method = 'radix'),]
```

The 'radix' sort method allows you to pass a vector values to the `decreasing=` argument, one logical value for each argument.

Output:

```r
# DAILY_INJ_DATE            PID     InjIndex
# 36        2020-12 42135311180000 4.782381e-02
# 35        2020-11 42135311180000 5.934792e-02
# 34        2020-10 42135311180000 5.881676e-02
# 33        2020-09 42135311180000 5.779698e-02
# 32        2020-08 42135311180000 6.436599e-02
# 31        2020-07 42135311180000 6.363578e-02
# 30        2020-06 42135311180000 6.005598e-02
# 29        2020-05 42135311180000 5.716388e-02
# 28        2020-04 42135311180000 4.607651e-02
# 27        2020-03 42135311180000 7.038377e-03
# 26        2020-02 42135311180000 3.821981e-05
# 25        2020-01 42135311180000 1.495620e-02
# 24        2019-12 42135311180000 8.238903e-03
# 23        2019-11 42135311180000 1.650376e-03
# 22        2019-10 42135311180000 1.906151e-02
# 21        2019-09 42135311180000 2.682569e-02
# 20        2019-08 42135311180000 2.032985e-03
# 19        2019-07 42135311180000 2.611961e-03
# 18        2019-06 42135311180000           NA
# 17        2019-05 42135311180000           NA
# 16        2019-04 42135311180000 0.000000e+00
# 15        2019-03 42135311180000 0.000000e+00
# 14        2019-02 42135311180000 0.000000e+00
# 13        2019-01 42135311180000 3.717472e-05
# 12        2018-12 42135311180000 1.412721e-04
# 11        2018-11 42135311180000 2.770103e-03
# 10        2018-10 42135311180000 1.004579e-04
# 9         2018-09 42135311180000 6.964712e-05
# 8         2018-08 42135311180000 1.011988e-04
# 7         2018-07 42135311180000 6.670304e-05
# 6         2018-06 42135311180000 6.972881e-05
# 5         2018-05 42135311180000 1.021467e-04
# 4         2018-04 42135311180000 3.659775e-03
# 3         2018-03 42135311180000 3.081981e-05
# 2         2018-02 42135311180000 7.164708e-05
# 1         2018-01 42135311180000 3.148835e-05
# 69        2020-12 42135335900000           NA
# 68        2020-11 42135335900000           NA
# 67        2020-10 42135335900000 6.911430e-02
# 66        2020-09 42135335900000 8.520753e-02
# 65        2020-08 42135335900000           NA
# 64        2020-07 42135335900000 5.850832e-02
# 63        2020-06 42135335900000           NA
# 62        2020-05 42135335900000           NA
# 61        2020-04 42135335900000 4.167411e-02
# 60        2020-03 42135335900000 2.347500e-02
# 59        2020-02 42135335900000           NA
# 58        2020-01 42135335900000 3.555675e-01
# 57        2019-12 42135335900000           NA
# 56        2019-11 42135335900000 1.314023e-01
# 55        2019-10 42135335900000           NA
# 54        2019-09 42135335900000           NA
# 53        2019-08 42135335900000 6.069270e-01
# 52        2019-07 42135335900000 2.168147e-01
# 51        2019-06 42135335900000 1.332213e-01
# 50        2019-02 42135335900000           NA
# 49        2019-01 42135335900000 1.915998e-02
# 48        2018-12 42135335900000 1.463395e-01
# 47        2018-11 42135335900000 1.254435e-01
# 46        2018-10 42135335900000 1.131914e-01
# 45        2018-09 42135335900000 1.404330e-01
# 44        2018-08 42135335900000 1.284961e-01
# 43        2018-07 42135335900000 1.269206e-01
# 42        2018-06 42135335900000 1.332258e-01
# 41        2018-05 42135335900000 1.361053e-01
# 40        2018-04 42135335900000 1.222742e-01
# 39        2018-03 42135335900000 5.671477e-02
# 38        2018-02 42135335900000 4.398696e-02
# 37        2018-01 42135335900000 5.795651e-02
```

Comment: Thnks! I like the 'Radix' method approach. Learned something new.